# Effects of time dilation on particles

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

According to time dilation, having 2 clocks, 1 further than the other from a gravitational center, makes the clocks run differently in respect to each other.

My question is, what exactly happens at a microscopic level? Does the space-time stretch between the atoms of the gears, making the clocks run at different speeds?

If we apply this concept to two twins living at different locations, would that mean that the atoms making up the body are slowed down as well because of this stretch?

One more thing, if we consider death as the sum of damage we accrued over time, is it as simple as saying one twin lives longer just because they have a more "stretched out" body(given the same damage over time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not some kind of change in space or a mechanical difference in the clocks. Time dilation means that time itself changes. In a gravitational field time is stretched out, so *everything* goes slower -- clocks, atoms, cells in your body, etc. -- as seen by a distant observer with less gravity.

The fundamental lesson of relativity is that there's no such thing as absolute time. Time is like a direction in spacetime, and different observers may have different directions of time, just as they may have different directions for "left-right". If someone says that an event was "2 meters to the left", it's perfectly reasonable to ask "your left or my left?" Similarly if you're talking about events in time, you have to specify the observer. To carry the analogy a bit further, the presence of gravity is like observers are standing on uneven ground, so their notion of distances in the left-right direction are also different.

Comment: hmm so if everything is stretched out, doesnt the ratio stay the same between atoms and distances? Meaning  that things should behave the same way. Also, what do you mean by "time is stretched out"? If I consider time as a period derived from an oscillation (like pendulums), that oscillation must physically change somehow, otherwise gravity doesnt make a difference. If you mean time as a fabric, then distances between atoms do get stretched out, without atoms getting stretched though, contradicting the first part of the comment. Please help me understand.

Comment: " _If I consider time as a period derived from an oscillation (like pendulums), that oscillation must physically change somehow,_ " . It DOES change. The time period of the oscillation reduces as time slows down. The oscillation slows down, atoms slow down, human cells slow down. EVERYTHING slows down

Comment: It's not "everything is stretched out", it's *time* is stretched out (relative to the distant observer). Time stretching out means the seconds on the surface of the Earth are literally longer than the ones high above. Time isn't space, and it isn't derived from space, it's something completely different; a 4th dimension separate from the other 3.

Comment: Im confused by both of your answers. @silverrahul, you are saying that even matter slows down, but is it an effect of being stretched? If so, why does time change since everything is stretched the same, keeping the ratios equal?

Comment: @EricSmith you are making up for silverrahul answer by saying its not the stretching. I do understand time is a 4th dimension, but time interacts with space since we measure time using oscillations. Since time has this interaction, it must slow down the matter we use to measure it, or else we would not be able to see a change in 2 pendulums. How would you explain this (let me know if the question is not clear)?

Comment: Someone next to the clock does not notice any difference. We don't *feel* slowed down because we're in the Earth's gravity well, we still perceive time as passing at 1 second/second. It's only someone higher up who would say that our time is slow. Also, I should emphasize that time and space need not be stretched in the same way due to gravity. The actual curvature may be quite complicated, depending on the configuration of matter.

Comment: @hey Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that not all technological ways to measure time will show the time difference according to GR predictions.

The most obvious case is a pendulum clock, where the period is $2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$. When the distance from the center of the earth tends to infinity, $g$ tends to zero, or the time stops according to the clock, what is not the case.

Other natural processes where gravity plays a role may also be affected in a way that doesn't match with $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ of GR equations.

But surely a form of light clock would measure the effect perfectly.